# function timeout in a celery task - multiprocess issue

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, celery

I would like to wrap a function in my code in a timeout. my problem is that this function runs within a celery task (and not as a celery task - which would make it easier to timeout).

I looked at the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

but I think there is a problem with opening a sub-processes in a celery worker process, and im getting errors like this:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

would love to hear some ways to work around this